# Rendering a state which is an array of strings. after push, gets me [object Object]

Tags: reactjs

When i push a button, that should push a message (str), it does not work.
 It displays [object Object]

Here is my simple code:

```
class Body extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            news: ["chao","chao"]
        }
        this.pushNews = this.pushNews.bind(this)
}

pushNews(content){

    this.setState({news: [...this.state.news, content]})

}
```

....

```
render(
 {return (
  <Button size="small" onClick={this.pushNews.bind("message")}>AddNews!    </Button>

{this.state.news.map((item, i) =>(
                            <div key={i}>{item.toString()}</div>
)
}
)
```

I get: [object Object]

I should see the input "meesage" being render :(

Comment: Could you format your render function ? This syntax will not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `bind` on your function to send it data and your `render` fucntion is not properly formatted :

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button size = "small" onClick = {() => this.pushNews("message")} > AddNews!</Button>
            {this.state.news.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.toString()}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `render` function of your component should always return a single parent node (or a fragment). I added a `div` as the parent of your elements.

An alternative with the newest JS standard would be to convert your function into an arrow function :

```
pushNews = content => event => {
```

And a simpler `onClick` : `onClick = {this.pushNews("message")}`

This will have the exact same result and allow you to remove the binding in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

Change the onClick call to something like this:

```
onClick={() => this.pushNews("message")}
```